# Cancelled Windows10 version 2004 feature update because there were apps open and now the Restart Now button does nothing when clicked

Tags: windows-10

I canceled the Windows 10 v2004 feature update in order to close a few apps, but after closing them, when I go back and click on the *Restart Now* button, there's a "progress loop" being displayed next to the button with nothing happening: 
[image: Windows10 Restart Now button]

What is the safe thing to do, wait another 10 minutes or however long it takes for the progress indicator to stop spinning?

Comment: Use a terminal and issue [`Shutdown /r`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown)

Comment: You can always restart your computer from the CONTROL+ALT+DEL screen

Comment: I didn't realize that rebooting with an update in a strange state was a safe thing to do.  The button came back after about 20 minutes of spinning.